# API request being proxied via Nginx needs rfc1123 date

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I am using a react app served using Nginx. I am trying to make a request to an external API, that requires a HMAC signature in the auth header, and also needs a date header set.

The API requires to use the following format: `Thu, 07 May 2020 15:38:19 GMT` in the request header. I tried using `date_gmt` which provides `Thursday, 07-May-2020 15:38:19 UTC`. To format it, I've explored map directives and the `<!--config>` type html tags, to no avail.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the location directive that you're using to proxy:

```
if ($date_gmt ~ "^(?<day>(\w{3}))\w+, (?<date>(\d{2}))-(?<month>(\w{3}))-(?<yeartime>(\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})) UTC$") {  
    set $day $day;
    set $date $date;
    set $month $month;
    set $yeartime $yeartime;
}
proxy_set_header Date "$day, $date $month $yeartime GMT";
```